# Difference between relativeOffset and offset in VAO with Direct Access Ext

Tags: opengl

Using The DSA Ext with opengl , API calls to guide opengl to the buffer format are :

```
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(  GLuint vaobj,
GLuint attribindex,
GLint size,
GLenum type,
GLboolean normalized,
GLuint relativeoffset);
```

and another one is :

```
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(  GLuint vaobj,
GLuint bindingindex,
GLuint buffer,
GLintptr offset,
GLsizei stride);
```

my question is what's the difference between relativeOffset and the offset in both function calls ? when i set one the results are ok but when you set both your layout will be incorrected and thus the results are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset in `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer` is the common offset for all attributes bound to that buffer. It's where the vbo data starts.

The offset in `glVertexArrayAttribFormat` is added to that common offset for that attribute.

This allows you to interleave attributes using a single vbo binding point. and change the vbo binding for those attributes in a single call.

To make an example:

```
struct Vertex {
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 normal;
}

glVertexAttribFormat(posAttrLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(Vertex, pos));
glVertexAttribBinding(posAttrLoc, vertexBindingPoint);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrLoc);

glVertexAttribFormat(normalAttrLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(Vertex, normal));
glVertexAttribBinding(normalAttrLoc, vertexBindingPoint);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalAttrLoc);
```

then to bind the buffer you pass the offset to where you put in where the data was uploaded to, this is 0 in the basic case.

```
glBindVertexBuffer(vertexBindingPoint, mesh.vbo, mesh.vboOffset, sizeof(Vertex));
```

Comment: so when data is tightly packed and there is no interleaving , like a situation where pos data is first and then the whole normals are , the offset bcomes one .

Comment: @mahdimahzuni then you'd use separate binding points for each attribute, the offset in `glVertexAttribFormat` become 0 and the offset in `glBindVertexBuffer` is where each attribute begins.

Comment: tnx superb explanation, performance wise is it bad to use two binding points or are they similar ?